# Missing Assembly reference System.Xml.XmlDocument

Tags: asp.net

Am trying to use Webservice in my application. Am converting my data to XML element and am passing but am my intellisense is not detecting the XmlDocument.
My code is

```
[WebMethod]
public XmlElement GetUserDetails(string userName)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ToString());
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UserInformation where UserName like @userName+'%'", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    // Create an instance of DataSet.
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    // Return the DataSet as an XmlElement.
    XmlDataDocument xmldata = new XmlDataDocument(ds);
    XmlElement xmlElement = xmldata.DocumentElement;
    return xmlElement;
}
```

Comment: Have you added reference to System.Xml ? You might want to check if you can return XmlElement as a contract object; see if it is Serializable

Answer (score 0):

You should add a reference to System.Xml.ddl in your project.

Comment: using System.Xml;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient; I had included these assemblies in adddition to the default references.Still am getting an error.Intellisense is suggesting to include a new class for XMLDataDocument.